# How to transform a slice to a list of index in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, slice

I want to transform a slice in some index so I can access each element of a vector at a time.

How can I do that?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please show some example code and what you've tried.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: can you reopen the questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `indices` method of the slice to generate a tuple that can be passed to `range`. You need to know the length of your instance though.

For example:

```
>>> sl = slice(2)  # or wherever you get that from
>>> length = 100
>>> list(range(*sl.indices(length)))
[0, 1]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, why there is a " * "?

Comment: That unpacks the tuple and passes each element as seperate parameter. That is needed because range expects 3 integer arguments not one tuple containing 3 integers.

Comment: What is the point of the `slice.indices` method since `range(*s.indices(length))` is equal to `range(length)[s]`?

Comment: @Maggyero There's a difference when there's a custom start or step. The question asked for a generic slice.

Comment: Do you have an example where the two expressions differ?